# Proving the number of internal nodes of a binary tree

Tags: graph-theory, induction, trees

Let $T$ be a nonempty 2-3 tree, so that it includes at least one node. Prove that if $T$ represents a subset $S\subseteq E$ such that $|S|= n\in \Bbb N$, then $T$ has at most $n-1$ internal nodes.

I figure you have to use induction, but I get stuck at the proof itself. Here's what I have so far:

Basis: When $n = 1$, $|S| = 1$, so $T$ is a nonempty tree with size $1$. Since it has size one, there is only one node, which is the root, which in this case is also a leaf, and cannot be an internal node. Then, $n – 1 = 1 – 1 = 0$ internal nodes, which proves that the basis holds.

Inductive hypothesis: Suppose that every subset $S\subseteq E$ with size $n$, represented by $T$, has at most $n – 1$ internal nodes.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is a 2-3 tree, and what is an internal node?

Comment: A 2-3 tree has 2 or 3 children per node. An internal node is a node that has children (so it is not a leaf)

Comment: And what does it mean for $T$ to “represent” a set of a particular size?

Comment: Sorry, my professor wrote it like that. It means that $T$ is a tree whose elements are from the subset $S$. Basically, the size (amount of nodes) of the tree $T$ is $n$.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that another way to state the problem is “Prove that every 2-3 tree has at least one leaf”?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes it can be stated like that.

Comment: So, do you see how any finite tree must have at least one leaf? In fact, any finite tree must have at least two leaves. Once you have figured it out, you should submit an answer for your question!